# Testing filters with jetty

Tags: java, testing, jetty, servlet-filters, guice-servlet

I've configured my servlets/filters using guice-servlet. With bindings like

```
 serve("/foo").with(HelloServlet.class);
```

Now, I want to test that mapping. I've used jetty-testing

```
private ServletTester tester;
private HttpTester request;
private HttpTester response;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    this.tester = new ServletTester();
    this.tester.setContextPath("/");
    this.tester.addEventListener(new Config()); //my guice servlet config goes there.

    this.tester.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", 0);
    this.tester.addServlet(FakeServlet.class, "/*");        <-----!!!!

    this.tester.start();
    this.request = new HttpTester();
    this.response = new HttpTester();
    this.request.setMethod("GET");
    this.request.setHeader("Host", "tester");
    this.request.setVersion("HTTP/1.0");
}

@Test
public void test() {
    this.request.setURI("/foo");
    this.response.parse(tester.getResponses(request.generate()));
    assertEquals(this.response.getContent(), "Hello World");
}
```

It works. But it made me to add some fake servlet that should bewer be invoked. How I can test it without adding such servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet spec requires a servlet for the doFilter chain to make sense.

If you don't want to create your own Servlet in the test cases, just use the [`org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.class`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html) instead (found in the [jetty-servlet.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jetty-servlet%22)).